# Comparing 2 TXT Files in Java with Same Content but Different Order

Tags: java, file, compare

I was wondering if there is a way to compare two txt files to compare if they have the same content but with not the same order. For example:

File1:
Adam 
Raymond
Robert

File2: 
Robert
Adam
Raymond

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can split your files into words and count the number of occurences of each word, then compare the results. You might want to use a `HashMap<String, Integer>` as a dictionary to store your words.

If you are sure that no word can repeat twice in your file, you can use a `SortedSet` instead of a `Map` and compare those two.